# How to add multiple accessoryCircular widget?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I created 3 circular widget for the lockscreen (IOS 16). They work great, but only 1 shows up in the simulator and my real iPhone. How can I make them all show up ?

Here is the switch I use:

```
struct PlaneCalcWidgetView: View {
    @Environment(\.widgetFamily) var size
    var entry: WidgetProvider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 16.0, *) {
            switch size {
            case .systemSmall:
                SmallWidgetView(entry: entry)
            case .systemMedium:
                MediumWidgetView(entry: entry)
            case .systemLarge:
                LargeWidgetView(entry: entry)
                
            case .accessoryCircular:
                gaugeCircularWidget(entry: entry)      <= First ONE
            case .accessoryCircular:
                gaugeMassCircularWidget(entry: entry)      <= second ONE
            case .accessoryCircular:
                gaugePaxCircularWidget(entry: entry)       <= third ONE

                
            case .accessoryRectangular:
                gaugeLinearWeatherWidget(entry: entry)
            @unknown default:
                Text("Unknown")
            }
        } else {
            switch size {
            case .systemSmall:
                SmallWidgetView(entry: entry)
            case .systemMedium:
                MediumWidgetView(entry: entry)
            case .systemLarge:
                LargeWidgetView(entry: entry)
            @unknown default:
                Text("Unknown")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can´t use `switch` like that. If you repeat the `case` it will take only the first entry every time.

Comment: Ok, can you show me a sample please ?

Comment: There is nothing to show. This will not work. You can have only one value for `accessoryCircular`

Comment: So how do other applications where there are several circular widgets do?

Comment: Could you add an image as example what you mean with `several circular widgets`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have multiple of same widget sizes in the same widget struct. In your case your widget struct is 'PlaneCalcWidgetView'.

Solution is to create another widget struct. Then Create a widget bundle to include 2 (or more) widget structs. Please note that you have to remove the @main from your original Widget struct. Instead, put @main in Widget Bundle.

```
@main
struct WidgetBundle_widget: WidgetBundle {

    @WidgetBundleBuilder
    var body: some Widget {
         PlaneCalcWidgetView_Widget()  //This is your Widget struct.
         PlaneCalcWidgetView_Second_Widget()
         PlaneCalcWidgetView_Third_Widget()
}
}
```